# How can I update one document at nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
    "_id": "5e28b029a0c8263a8a56980a",
    "name": "Recruiter",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5e28b0980f89ba3c0782828f",
            "targetLink": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-kelsall-7aa0926b/",
            "name": "Dan Kelsall",
            "headline": "Content Marketing & Copywriting",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "result": 1,
                    "name": "VISIT"
                },
                {
                    "result": 1,
                    "name": "FOLLOW"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e28b0980f89ba3c078283426f",
            "targetLink": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/56wergwer/",
            "name": "56wergwer",
            "headline": "asdgawehethre",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "result": 1,
                    "name": "VISIT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is one of my mongodb document. I'd like to update `data->actions->result`
So this is what I've done

```
Campaign.updateOne({
    'data.targetLink': "https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-kelsall-7aa0926b/",
    'data.actions.name': "Follow"
}, {$set: {'data.$.actions.result': 0}})
```

But it seems not updating anything and even it can't find the document by this 'data.actions.name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [the positional filtered operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) since the regular positional operator ($) can only be used for one level of nested arrays:

```
Campaign.updateOne(
     { "_id": "5e28b029a0c8263a8a56980a", "data.targetLink": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-kelsall-7aa0926b/" },
     { $set: { "data.$.actions.$[action].result": 0 } },
     { arrayFilters: [ { "action.name": "Follow" } ] }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Simply amazing