# Is this the correct way to model data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

I am new to data modelling and am working on a personal project in which users can upload photos to containers. These containers can be nested (for example: "Japan" container may have a sub container called "Cats" in which you can store pictures of all the cats you saw in Japan).

I am imagining 3 entities: Users, Containers, and Photos structured in the following way:

Users Collection:

```
{
  User_id: userId101,
  userName: “Chase”,
  Email: “chase@email.com”,
  Containers: [{name: “Thailand”, parentContainer: null}, {name: “Food”, parentContainer:
                     “Thailand”],
}
```

Containers Collection:

```
{
  Id: cont_01,
  Name: “Thailand”,
  ownedBy: userId101
  parentContainer: null,
  Photos: [“photoId1”, “photoId2”, etc.]
{
```

Photos Collection:

```
{
  Id: photo_01,
  userRef: userId101
  Url: “www.unsplash.com/1279178298”
}
```

I just want to know if I am missing any major detail that will break this before I spend weeks building this out.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Could you describe your data access cases ? Are you going to always query by user or is there any case to get only photos no matter which user they belong to ?

Comment: Each user will always be accessing only their own photos. I plan to display a list of clickable top level containers, which will show photos and clickable sub containers for that user only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really multiple factors that can be taken into consideration here. First of all you don't need to think that every "entity" should have a separate collection (like in SQL) BSON can handle nested arrays like below:

```
{
    Id: cont_01,
    Name: "Thailand",
    ownedBy: userId101
    parentContainer: null,
    Photos: [ { id: "photo_01", "www.unsplash.com/1279178298" }]
}
```

"Joining" ([$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)) the data in MongoDB is an additional overhead so keep it merged unless you have a good reason to divide into multiple collections.

Having the data modeled like above gives you a possibility to use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) to get a tree of parent-child relationships.

This is what I would start with. As a next step you can consider embedding user data into each container (denormalized) to avoid using `$lookups` or having single `user` document with an array of containers having embedded `photos` - more difficult to maintain (updates are a bit more complicated like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868199/how-can-i-update-object-of-subarray)) but better read performance since you don't need lookups.

The drawback of having extremely large documents is also 16MB document size limitation which is a lot but it's good to keep that in mind.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had a hunch that I could have minimized the number of collections I was using but I wasn't sure what the best way to do that was. Thanks so much for taking the time.